# Linking YouTube Channel with Google+ Profile

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I have a YouTube channel and a Google+ Profile and I want to link them together to have managers on YouTube. I do not get a button saying would you like to link this to Google+ nor do I get one that allows me to add/remove managers. How do I link the two together?

Answer (score 1):

Linking your YouTube channel to a Google+ page is simple, you can link your channel with your Google page on the advanced settings page in YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced).

If this does not work out for you, you can contact Google about your issue https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/ytgplus.

I hope this will answer your question!